# How to delete text between a word and the end-of-cell marker

Tags: vba, ms-word

[image: img]

How can I delete the text between `<de>` and the end-of-cell marker throughout my Word document?

I have reached the following code from my previous question. It appeared not to be working because my lines end with end-of-cell markers. So now I need to update this to delete the text between `<de>`and the end-of-cell marker.

I am unable to implement that in this code.

```
Sub FindTheDeleteToEndOfLine()
Dim searchTerm As String
Dim bFound As Boolean

searchTerm = "<de>"
Selection.HomeKey wdStory
'Basic Find settings
With Selection.Find
    .Forward = True
    .wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With

'Execute the Find
Do
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = searchTerm
        bFound = .Execute
        If bFound Then
            Selection.MoveEnd wdLine, 1
            Selection.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
            Selection.Delete
        End If
    End With
    Loop While bFound
End Sub
```

Update: I worked out a new code less complicated, but again i am unale to define the `arng.words` in order to delete last part after `<de>`:

```
    Dim arng As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long
With Selection.Tables(1)
For i = 1 To .Rows.Count
For j = 1 To .Columns.Count
Set arng = .Cell(i, j).Range
arng.End = arng.End - 1
'Text = "<de>"
If Right(arng.Words, 1) = "<de>" Then
arng.Words.Last = Left(arng.Words, Len(arng.Words) - 1)
End If
Next j
Next i
End With
```

Comment: Whenever you have a problem with your code you should explain HOW it's "not working". That provides important information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, for example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "<de>"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
      .End = .Cells(1).Range.End - 1
      .Delete
    End If
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're encountering here is due to how Word reacts to a selection inside a cell: as soon as it reaches the end of the cell it selects the entire cell.

I've modified the code (which makes it more "complicated") to take this into account. In order to deal with this, there is now a `Range` object in the code that stores the original "Found" point in the document. After extending the selection to the end of the line, and moving it back one character (which means the entire cell is selected), the starting point is re-set to the "found" position.

```
Sub FindTheDeleteToEndOfCell()
    Dim searchTerm As String
    Dim bFound As Boolean
    Dim rngFound As Word.Range

    searchTerm = "<de>"
    Selection.HomeKey wdStory
    'Basic Find settings
    With Selection.Find
        .Forward = True
        .wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

    'Execute the Find
    Do
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = searchTerm
            bFound = .Execute
            If bFound Then
                Set rngFound = Selection.Range
                Selection.MoveEnd wdLine, 1
                Selection.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
                Selection.Start = rngFound.Start
                Selection.Delete
            End If
        End With
    Loop While bFound
End Sub
```

Comment: I am really thankful for you sir, that worked beautifully !